# .NET Core WEB API Modelbinding: how to make use of JSON Schema validation

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, jsonschema

I have a JSON Schema and want to make use of it iny my PUT/POST/PATCH API endpoints.

Basically I want to make use of JSON Schema validation and handle invalid JSON in the Http request pipeline.

I did not findy anything on the internet on that matter so I start thinking that I might missunderstood something essential here.

I assumed I could register Json Schema with options as middleware in startup but well, how can this be done ?

Comment: .NET supports model binding 'out of the box' with JSON as input. Are you wanting to actually read the raw JSON from requests? It's not clear from your question

Comment: I want to validate JSON input against given Schema and handle requests with invalid data right away.

Answer (score 2):

In a previous version of the site, I used [this middleware](https://github.com/gregsdennis/json-everything/blob/b31ef285ebeae78daae986ef4232bf634c422d20/TryJsonEverything/Services/SchemaValidationMiddleware.cs) for https://json-everything.net, which is my showcase site for my JSON library suite.  It's powered by [JsonSchema.Net](https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonSchema.Net/), which itself is part of the suite.

It's likely not the best way to do it, but it works well.  I'm still playing with it before I put it into a library, but you're welcome to copy it for your uses.

Comment: Thx, I will have a look at this. I am a litte bit confused because I thought this would be kind of a common thing but apparently it is not. This makes me wondering if I really should use Json Schema in the first place.

Comment: I think it helps the client more than the API.  The client gets nicer responses if the input is bad.

Comment: I've updated the links in this post as I've since updated the site to use Blazor WASM and so the middleware is no longer necessary.

Answer (score 1):

You'll want to check out [OpenAPI](https://oai.github.io/) -- it provides the specification that builds on top of JSON Schema to enable request and response validation, document generation, code generation, and lots more.

Also see https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/IMPLEMENTATIONS.md for a list of implementations (although there are many more out there that aren't listed, too).

Comment: I started with studying https://json-schema.org/ and checked validation implementations in C# which is Newtonsoft Json.NET. But know I see that the picture may be bigger than this? Well I think I have to study again.

Comment: Btw, I am already using Swagger for my API. But I don't know how validation comes into play..

Comment: I think OpenAPI is too much for us right now. API is not really public and is beeing developed with client anyway. Reading about json schema the idea came up, to make use of it both in frontend as in api to validate models.